# Accurate Thread.sleep for a simple clock application?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a simple clock thread that updates the time once per second. In order to achieve that, I used `Thread.sleep(1000)` to call the worker class every 1 second however, it seems like the clock runs slightly faster than my computer clock. Is there a way to normalize the sleep clock so that it will wake up exactly in a second, same with my computer clock?

Comment: Are you using System.currentTimeMillies() to take take?

Comment: There is no guarantee that it will not run slower than your computer (when under load)

Comment: You cannot rely on `sleep` to be accurate.

Comment: Not unless you're running on a real time operating system.

Answer (score 2):

This should be expected, as per the [JavaDoc:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease
>   execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the
>   precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread
>   does not lose ownership of any monitors.

What you could do, could be to sleep less, say, 400ms and then check to see if the time has changed.

Alternatively, you could use a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and fire events once every second and update your time.

Edit: As per your comment, you could do something like so:

```
long initTime = System.getTimeinMillis();
while(true)
{
      Thread.sleep(200);
      if((System.getTimeInMillis() - initTime) >= 1000)
      {
          initTime = System.getTimeInMillis();
          //Update your timer.
      }
}
```

Comment: A while ago, I saw a simple fix by checking with currentTimeMillies() everytime it wakes up, and have a differential sleep time. But I cannot find that example anywhere again?

Comment: @Yonk: I have updated my response. This is something akin to my first recommendation.

Comment: @Yonk keep in mind that even `currentTimeMillies()` isn't always 100% accurate.

Comment: I wouldn't hack around this with a loop like that: if sleeping 1000ms is not accurate, sleeping for 200ms isn't likely to be much more accurate.  Now you've introduced that error multiple times...

Comment: @StevenSchlansker: That is why I recommended the use of a `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to go to sleep, wake up(possibly prematurely) and check time again to go to sleep.

Under heavy system load, your timer thread does not get scheduled and thread may not wake up from sleep resulting your clock going off time.

But its always about showing correct time, whenever possible.

General suggestion: maximize sleep to keep wake ups minimum(each wakeup involves one context switch).

Here is something I wrote for myself:

```
   /**
     * Put the calling thread to sleep.
     * Note, this thread does not throw interrupted exception,
     * and will not return until the thread has slept for provided time.
     *
     * @param milliSecond milliSecond time to sleep in millisecond
     */
    public static void sleepForcefully(int milliSecond) {
        final long endingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + milliSecond;
        long remainingTime = milliSecond;
        while (remainingTime > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(remainingTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            }
            remainingTime = endingTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
```

This type of logic is used all over timers, pingers, etc in JDK and other places.